# How to set design rules in JGraphX graph editor?

Tags: java, scilab, jgraphx, xcos

In my graph editor program i have created a blocks(mxcells) with input and output port, It looks like 
[image]

I want to set design rules as, While creating edge between ports.

> 1. Out put port should connected to input port only.
> 2. Input port should not connected to another input port..etc...

How can i set these rules? Is there any method in JGraphX for Design Rule Check(DRC)?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully did it by using mxMultiplicity.. Used following program for reference [Link](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/validation.html)